# possible to have plugin not install for one header in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a theme that uses an instance of jquery (a fader) that conflicts with a plugin that I need when it's also activated.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have it so that the plugin that uses the jquery ONLY installs on the default header.php, and not the one I have set up that uses the other instance of jquery so that they don't conflict?

Or is it possible to have my header-page.php file not use the header function?  If I remove that, then it works... but I lose the styles.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

This is the code the plugin interjects...

```
     add_action('admin_init', 'editor_admin_initxx');
     add_action('admin_head', 'editor_admin_headxx');
     function my_scripts_methodbb() {
     wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
     wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: ya, its possible.  Just find the hook the plugin uses to attach its scripts, and write some logic into that so it only adds the scripts on the pages you want.

Comment: It's certainly possible. You could use a PHP if check with a flag (variable) on the pages that need each type of jQuery, or you could use jQuery/JS to detect when the plugin is present. Give something a try, then ask for help with it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually at a a loss on how I can do this.. this is the code the plugin uses which then integrates itself into the wordpress header. Edited original post.

Comment: Question: are you only including the jquery script once, because multiple includes of it will cause errors.

Comment: Trying to only do once... trouble is that these jquery plugins rely on different versions of it.... 1.6, 1.9, 1.7 etc.  I've tried to do a noconflict script for them but it doesn't work so I've been just includig the various scripts in a seperate header that uses them... header1 for page1 header2 for page2 etc so they don't conflict.  WIth this plugin it installs at the basic header.php file which is why I need to find a solution.  Obviously am open to any suggestion.